# Do I need to put comma in this place at the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

The sentence is:

"A line is composed of a lot of points. From now on(**,**) this point we call “one dimensional”

The options are:

> 1) "A line is composed of a lot of points. From now on, this point we
>   call “one dimensional”
>
> 2) "A line is composed of a lot of points. From now on this point we
>   call “one dimensional”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas are usually best used only when they clarify things. In this case I would use a comma.

So the first option (using a comma):

> A line is composed of a lot of points. From now on, this point we call “one dimensional."

The following was part of my answer before the OP was edited:

{First, singular count nouns such as *line* almost always require a determiner. In most cases this will be an article. Thus, in standard English it will be ***A*** line... when talking about a typical line.}

Comment: Regarding to "from now on - we called it". This defect happened after I changed the origin sentence "from now on, it's called etc." So, I changed the pronoun only, inadvertently.